# angularjs ng-bind not working after stored in a var

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-bind is not binding data  if  I  assign a var for it. Why?

```
var output = $scope.output;
      output = JSON.stringify(txt);
```

Plnkr : --> http://plnkr.co/edit/srYQnpHudt7gfeOXN1ff?p=preview

Comment: did my answer solve your issue. If so please mark it as the correct answer to close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

http://plnkr.co/edit/3VRAlVS63bqSXxTd5l0N?p=preview

Is this what you wanted:

```
    app.controller('cCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.generate = function () {
    var txt  = $scope.objInput;

     var output = JSON.stringify(txt);
       $scope.output = output ;
    };

});// Fin qCtrl
```

Comment: yes but i want to use it  like this. 

var output = $scope.output;
output = JSON.stringify(txt);

Comment: You just overwrote the local var value `output`. It seems like maybe you think setting that value will set `$scope.output`? That is not how things work.

Comment: Do you want to display the output or just use it within the generate method? Seems like you are just creating variables for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the variable to ng-bind, I have changes this way, here the objInput is assigned txt and then its converted to string and then stored to output variable and then assigned scope variable output.

`$scope.generate = function (){
      var txt  = $scope.objInput;
      var output = JSON.stringify(txt);
      $scope.output = output;
};`

Hope this helps.